# np.linalg.inv() leads to array full of np.nan

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse

I am trying to calculate the inverse of [a matrix](https://gigamove.rwth-aachen.de/en/download/67e19a535e5304d72a767d30eb4b1fea) via:

```
A = pd.read_csv("A_use.csv", header = None)

I = np.identity(len(A))

INV = np.linalg.inv(I - A)
```

However, the resulting array is full of `np.nan`.

[image]

I don't understand why that's the case.
I've tried to replace all `np.nan` values in A (although there shouldn't be any) via `A[np.isnan(A)] = 0` but the problem persists.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The reason is an `np.inf` value in at least column 293. The `np.inf` value can be replaced via `A[np.isinf(A)] = 0`. If `np.inf` is replaced with zero, there are no `np.nan` values in L.

Answer (score 4):

Not all matrices have an inverse. A matrix has and inverse if its determinant is non-zero.

Check first whether

```
np.linalg.det(I-A) ~= 0
```

If it's non-zero, then you should be able to do

```
np.linalg.inv(I-A)
```

Second, make sure `I-A` does not have a single `NaN` value. If it does, then computing its inverse will result to a matrix of `NaN` values.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in A.

There could be nan values in the dataframe.
The matrix A could be singular, please check if `np.linalg.det(A)` is not 0

Then I would pass to the function `np.linalg.inv` a numpy array using `pd.DataFrame.to_numpy` (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)

Comment: `np.linalg.det(A)` returns a float with `np.nan`. Also `pd.DataFrame.to_numpy` does not do the job unfortunately.

Comment: I, therefore, think that there is a nan value inside A. Please, if the matrix is relatively small check every entry, otherwise try to calculate the determinant of a smaller matrix, for example, `np.linalg.det(A[:100,:100])`

Comment: The matrix has a dimension of 15908*15908 = 253,064,464 fields. Actually, having a `np.nan` value in the matirx was also what I first suspected but since I apply `A[np.isnan(A)] = 0` there should not be a `np.nan` value, or not?

Comment: yes, I agree.
Another possibility is an overflow
maybe try to calculate the `np.linalg.det` for smaller matrix and then logarithmically increase for example  `np.linalg.det(A[:3,:3])`  `np.linalg.det(A[:30,:30])`   `np.linalg.det(A[:300,:300])`   `np.linalg.det(A[:3000,:3000])`   `np.linalg.det(A[:10000,:10000])` or something like this, if it is numerical you will see that for smaller matrix you will get a result and then rapidly increase the value of the result

Comment: another possibility is to use   `np.linalg.pinv` that computes the inverse in a different method (but I do not think it will solve)

Comment: My aim is to get the inverse of `I-A`. The NumPy documentation says np.linalg.det `Compute the determinant of an array`. Sorry for being ignorant or bad at maths but how does `np.linalg.det` helps me here?

Comment: because if a matrix has a determinant of 0 it is not invertible. if you look on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix you see that det(A) = 1/det(A^-1). Therefore if the matrix has a determinant of 0 it it not invertible (you cannot use `np.linalg.inv`). It works the same if the determinant has some nan values